# Compiling an allegro5 program using make

Tags: c, makefile, allegro5

I have a program called zone.c that uses the allegro5 library.

I have a makefile that consists of just these two lines.

```
zone: zone.c
        gcc zone.c -o zone $(pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0)
```

when I type "make" I get these errors:

/tmp/ccyCx3Hy.o: In function `main':
zone.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to`al_install_system'
zone.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `al_create_display'
zone.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to`al_map_rgb'
zone.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `al_clear_to_color'
zone.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to`al_map_rgb'
zone.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `al_draw_filled_circle'
zone.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to`al_map_rgb'
zone.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `al_draw_filled_circle'
zone.c:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to`al_flip_display'
zone.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `al_rest'
zone.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to`al_destroy_display'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [zone] Error 1

But if I just copy out the line "gcc zone.c -o zone $(pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0)" and run it manually, it compiles fine and the program works.

If I use similar makefiles to compile programmes that don't use allegro5, then make works.

Does anybody have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a literal `$` in your rule, you have to escape it from make by writing `$$` instead:

```
zone: zone.c
        gcc zone.c -o zone $$(pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0)
```